# What must I do in Istanbul airport

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, turkey

I'm travelling to Havana Cuba and I'm Congolese. And Turkish airlines doesn't have a direct flight to cuba from Congo. So is it possible to get a flight to Istanbul then from there get another flight to Cuba the following day? With the same company(Turkish airlines).

If I can already book the second flight (Istanbul-Havana) from Congo. And are they gonna give me a Transit Visa for that 1 day in Istanbul? must I apply from Congo or at the airport?

Comment: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/. You can get that eVisa faster than the first answer here.

Comment: You should book the itinerary as a single ticket, e.g. FIH-HAV. Turkish Airlines will sort out your connections, change your baggage, and you can stay in Istanbul transit area without a visa. If you purchase them separately you may have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will exit the airport, if so you need a visa as you are visa-free only if you stay inside the airport:

> **Question**: I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I need to get transit visa?
>
> **Answer**: If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjdq7rO5LfkAhUitnEKHfDXAbgQFjACegQIDBAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mfa.gov.tr%2Ffrequently-asked-questions.en.mfa&usg=AOvVaw15pLPJ9k6RV9Hct3wdzyKa))

If you need a visa, you can easily apply for an [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/) online.